# Body height 100% conflict with bootstrap container and flex

Tags: bootstrap-4

I have a site with the same body and html (meaning that I am using ASP.NET MVC). Some pages contain tables that have to be the same size as the browser and some pages with forms that have to support scroll. Because of the pages where I need the content to fill the browser height I had to set the height 100% on body and html.
But on the page that should support scroll two divs with class row are overlapped

```
Please see the below reproduction
```

https://jsfiddle.net/w0s4xmc0/52112/

Is there a way to arrange the layout and not change the 100% on body and html?

Comment: It's hard to understand the question. Can you clarify please?

Comment: Can you use `height:100vh` ?

Comment: @Zim make Another the green div be after the red div and not overlapped

Comment: @Jakub Muda I could but how do I eliminate the navigation bar height? The reason I used the 100% was that the navigation bar height is dynamic and not fixed.